# Separating product pages for bundle or configurable products

Tags: product, magento-2.1, configurable-product, magento-community, bundled-product

I have a somewhat complicated task at hand and I am looking for guidance.

I need to either have:

1. A bundled product with the simple products that make it up on separate pages but then show as the bundle on checkout.

***or***

2. Have a way to have certain simple products come together at checkout and be segmented from others, which is preferred.

Basically, the website has one customizable product but the user interface needs to go like this:

**Step 1 (page 1):** Select the base part of the product from 2 options.

**Step 2 (page 2):** Select the 2nd base part of the product from 8 options.

**Step 3 (page 3):** Select from a large variety of components to add to the product. This page is already built on the front end and is a very custom drag and drop interface.

**Step 4 (page 4):** Go to cart and see 1 product or bundle of products making the end result.

**Step 5:** Still on page 4 have the option to either build another one or go to checkout.

This may seem like a job for a configurable product and I'm not opposed to that but still, I run into the issue of the UI. At that point, I would have to somehow separate the attributes (options) your selecting from into separate pages following the steps above. Also, we have some inventory issues with Configurable products since you can't track inventory of an attribute with Magento.

Any guidance is welcomed!!